# ADB Error codes

Tags: android

We have an android device and as part of testing I need to excute a console test application on the target device. If the test application detects an error it returns -1.

I can use adb shell to run the test applications remotely on the target but I can't find a way of getting back the return code. I need this so I that I can build this into an automated test suite.

I could try grepping the console output for some failure text but that is a bit grubby. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Whatever adb execute, it always return 0.

Comment: [Issue 3254:  adb shell doesn't return exit code of program](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3254)

Comment: Still not fixed in 2018. I use a wrapper shell on android side and let this write the code into a file which is then downloaded.

Comment: In 2023 this has been fixed unless the device restarts from the command. I ran `adb shell false` it returns 1

Answer (score 9):

This is a workaround to get the exit code:
adb shell '{your command here} > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?'

This is a wrapper around adb in Ruby:

```
def adb(opt)
  input = "#{adb_command} #{opt[:command]} #{opt[:params]}"
  puts "Executing #{input}...\n"
  output = nil
  exit_code = 0

  def wait_for(secs)
    if secs
      begin
        Timeout::timeout(secs) { yield }
      rescue
        print 'execution expired'
      end
    else
      yield
    end
  end

  wait_for(opt[:timeout]) do
    case opt[:command]
    when :install, :push, :uninstall
      output, exit_code = `#{input}`, $?.to_i
    when :shell
      input = "#{adb_command} shell \"#{opt[:params]}; echo \\$?\""
      output = `#{input}`.split("\n")
      exit_code = output.pop.to_i
      output = output.join("\n")
    else
      raise 'Error: param command to adb not defined!'
    end
  end

  return if opt[:ignore_fail] and output =~ /#{opt[:ignore_fail]}/
  raise output unless exit_code == 0
end
```

Comment: Have you ever needed to use `echo \$?` ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use Facebook's [fb-adb](https://github.com/facebook/fb-adb), a "A better shell for Android devices" which "propagates program exit status instead of always exiting with status 0".