# How can I run cargo tests on another machine without the Rust compiler?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know that the compiler can run directly on `arm-linux-androideabi`, but the Android emulator (I mean emulation of ARM on x86/amd64) is slow,
so I don't want to use `cargo` and `rustc` on the emulator, I only want to run tests on it.

I want to cross-compile tests on my PC (`cargo test --target=arm-linux-androideabi --no-run`?), and then upload and run them on emulator,
hoping to catch bugs like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42918).

How can I run `cargo test` without running `cargo test`? Is it as simple as running all binaries that were built with `cargo test --no-run`?

Comment: So you want specifies the target of rustc ?

Comment: @Stargateur No, I want to run tests without `cargo` and `rustc` on machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two kinds of tests supported by `cargo test`, one is the normal tests (`#[test] fn`s and files inside `tests/`), the other is the doc tests.

The normal tests *are* as simple as running all binaries. The test is considered successful if it exits with error code 0.

Doc tests *cannot* be cross-tested. Doc tests are compiled and executed directly by `rustdoc` using the compiler libraries, so the compiler must be installed on the ARM machine to run the doc tests. In fact, running `cargo test --doc` when HOST ≠ TARGET will do nothing.

So, the answer to your last question is **yes** as long as you don't rely on doc-tests for coverage.

---

Starting from Rust 1.19, `cargo` supports [target specific runners](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/3954), which allows you to  specify a script to upload and execute the test program on the ARM machine.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
adb push "$1" "/sdcard/somewhere/$1"
adb shell "chmod 755 /sdcard/somewhere/$1 && /sdcard/somewhere/$1" 
# ^ note: may need to change this line, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9379400
```

Put this to your [`.cargo/config`](http://doc.crates.io/config.html):

```ini
[target.arm-linux-androideabi]
runner = ["/path/to/your/run/script.sh"]
```

then `cargo test --target=arm-linux-androideabi` should Just Work™.

---

If your project is hosted on GitHub and uses Travis CI, you may also want to check out [`trust`](https://github.com/japaric/trust). It provides a pre-packaged solution for testing on many architectures including ARMv7 Linux on the CI (no Android unfortunately).

Comment: Great, that is exactly how I want it to be implemented.

Comment: Hi, how can I compile for arm architecture? I originally use `cargo ndk` but it seems not to support such testing; if I use raw cargo build command, it errors when compiling to arm.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation for testing on Android would be to use [`dinghy`](https://github.com/snipsco/dinghy) which provides nice wrapper commands for building and testing on Android/iOS devices/emulator/simulators.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever might still be interested in this:
run `cargo -v test` with `-v`

Then look for this output

```
 Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 21.31s
     Running `/my-dir/target/release/deps/my-binary-29b03924d05690f1`
```

Then just copy the test binary `/my-dir/target/release/deps/my-binary-29b03924d05690f1` to the machine without rustc