# Is there a way to directly run the program built by Cargo in gdb or lldb?

Tags: debugging, rust, gdb, lldb, rust-cargo

Is there a way to run the program built by Cargo immediately in `gdb`? `cargo` has lots of functions and can run the program, so it seems plausible.

The expected command would be something like `cargo debug`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's nothing like this currently built into Cargo.

There's a few issues ([1](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3670), [2](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1924)) to better support similar issues.

The best thing you could do at the moment would be to write a [Cargo subcommand](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/wiki/Third-party-cargo-subcommands) that does exactly what you need.

#### A workaround

Without creating a subcommand, you can glue together a few features to get something close.

Start by configuring [a custom runner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44947640/155423) for your architecture.

**.cargo/config**

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
runner = ["/tmp/gg/debugger.sh"]
```

Then write a little script to be the test runner. If an environment variable is set, it will start the debugger, otherwise it will just run the program:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $DEBUG ]]; then
    exec $*
else
    exec lldb $*
fi
```

Then you just need to set the variable:

```
$ cargo test
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running target/debug/deps/gg-e5d6c92730ca3c30

running 0 tests

$ DEBUG=1 cargo test
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running target/debug/deps/gg-e5d6c92730ca3c30
(lldb) target create "/private/tmp/gg/target/debug/deps/gg-e5d6c92730ca3c30"
Current executable set to '/private/tmp/gg/target/debug/deps/gg-e5d6c92730ca3c30' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

See also:

- [How can I run cargo tests on another machine without the Rust compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44947640/155423)
- [How to debug Rust unit tests on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50707118/155423)